# how to do if else in ssh pseudo-tty allocation to remote server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tty

I tried to `ssh` with `pseudo-tty allocation` to remote server using the following bash script;

```
ssh -t -t user@remote-host
if [ -d "/test/dir_test" ]; then
  sudo chown -R user:admin /test/dir_test/
  sudo rm -rf /test/dir_test/*
else        
  sudo mkdir /test/dir_test/
fi
```

that checks if `/test/dir_test` exists on `remote-host`, if not create such dir `test/dir_test` on remote-host; but the script does not work, I am wondering how to do it using `ssh` with `pseudo-tty allocation` in this case.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to quote the commands that is to be sent to the server like so:

```
ssh -t -t user@remote-host "
if [ -d '/test/dir_test' ]; then
  sudo chown -R user:admin /test/dir_test/
  sudo rm -rf /test/dir_test/*
else        
  sudo mkdir /test/dir_test/
fi"
```

Be aware that `sudo` needs a password unless otherwise specified in its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could send commands via stdin with a heredoc:

```
ssh -tt user@remote-host <<EOT
if [ -d "/test/dir_test" ]; then
  sudo chown -R user:admin /test/dir_test/
  sudo rm -rf /test/dir_test/*
else        
  sudo mkdir /test/dir_test/
fi
exit
EOT
```

Notice the final exit command.